# RADIUS and IEC 62351

Tags: rbac, freeradius, radius

IEC 62351-8 specifies that Role Based Access Control are used to reduce and limit user access to a system based on their role.

The concept is to perform an action a user need to authenticate themselves (username/password) and have a role with the correct access rights.

How would we implement this in Radius/Freeradius?

As far as I can tell Radius can authenticate based on user/password, but does not by default provide an indication of the role/group the user is asking permissions for.

For example  if I have a user with both operator and security admin roles, how would they go about requesting security admin role?

I am presuming this has something to do with attributes, but there is no obvious attribute to do this

Answer (score 0):

having the same problem this is the solution i will use:

Radius defines a Vendor-Specific attribute, in which the information about the roles etc. can be stored.

I found an example here: 
 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317167505_Handling_Role-based_Access_Control_in_the_Digital_Grid
which propose the vendor specific type to be build up as follows:

BEGIN-VENDOR IEC

- ATTRIBUTE RoleID     1  integer
- ATTRIBUTE roleDefinition  2  string
- ATTRIBUTE AoR     3  string
- ATTRIBUTE revision     4  integer
- ATTRIBUTE ValidFrom     5  string
- ATTRIBUTE ValidTo    6  string

End-VENDOR IEC

Handling Role-based Access Control in the Digital Grid (PDF Download Available). Available from: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317167505_Handling_Role-based_Access_Control_in_the_Digital_Grid [accessed Jan 09 2018].

---

And here an example of a dictonary file of FreeRadius with the possibility to send two differnet Tokens (id 0 and 1), where the tokeId is calculated out of the Attribute Type):

VENDOR International-Electrotechnical-Commission 41912

BEGIN-VENDOR International-Electrotechnical-Commission

ATTRIBUTE IEC62351-8-RoleID-0               1      integer

ATTRIBUTE IEC62351-8-roleDefinition-0       2      string

ATTRIBUTE IEC62351-8-aor-0                  3      string

ATTRIBUTE IEC62351-8-revision-0             4      integer

ATTRIBUTE IEC62351-8-ValidFrom-0            5      string

ATTRIBUTE IEC62351-8-ValidTo-0              6      string

ATTRIBUTE IEC62351-8-RoleID-1               11     integer

ATTRIBUTE IEC62351-8-roleDefinition-1       12     string

ATTRIBUTE IEC62351-8-aor-1                  13     string

ATTRIBUTE IEC62351-8-revision-1             14     integer

ATTRIBUTE IEC62351-8-ValidFrom-1            15     string

ATTRIBUTE IEC62351-8-ValidTo-1              16     string

END-VENDOR International-Electrotechnical-Commission

Comment: No, as this is currently not standardized anywhere yet , i would be really surprised if you find it anywhere.
I added an example in my answer above how my dictonary for freeRadius is currently defined.

Comment: Mmm I dislike the use of multiple attribute numbers to define different tokens. It'd be better to do that with tags or using groups TLVs, or just by using multiple instances of the same attribute.

Anyway i've added the definitions from the paper to FR4.